# Is it possible to store edge data layers?

Tags: texturing, uv, edges, data-blocks

Something that I do frequently in blender is use a UV map for coordinates to map an otherwise procedural texture, such as when texturing a snake. I don't always know where the best seams would be beforehand, so I like to try putting them in a different places and create multiple UV layers. So I was wondering, in the same way as one can switch between multiple UV maps, is it possible to store edge data sets, for example, save multiple sets of UV seams or edge creases and toggle between them?

Answer (score 2):

You can save "edge data" like that in the form of seams on UV maps.  Use "seams from islands" operation in UV editor to select what your seams would have been for that UV map.

Can also maintain multiple copies of your model, and use a data transfer modifier to copy seam status (or all sorts of other edge statuses.)